# Can't figure out how to print a Coordinate on a Console Window

Tags: c#

I'm trying to print a symbol '@' on the console window by using for loops. Can't figure out how it should be. I tried, but ended up on the correct Y coordinate, but not correct X Coordinate.

```
        Class1 Point = new Class1(2, 8);
        Console.WriteLine("X = {0}", Point.X);
        Console.WriteLine("Y = {0}", Point.Y);


        for (int y = 0; y < Point.Y; y++)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("");
            if (y == Point.Y - 1)
            {
                for (int x = 0; x < Point.X; x++)
                {
                    Console.Write(" @");
                }
            }

        }
    }$
```

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/pl-pl/library/system.console.setcursorposition(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: What are you trying to do exactly? Write a symbol at a specific coordinates? Write many symbols from [0,0] until it reach a specific coordinates?

Comment: Only a single symbol on a specific coordinate on a console window. It could be any symbol but only one symbol not multiple! By the way I got little closer Where I want to be. I just need to figure out how to print only one symbol now two

Comment: So you are using the Console class but you haven't read its docs. If you do you will find a little method named [SetCursorPosition](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.console.setcursorposition(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: I know about that method. But I know it's silly but I want to do it using for loops xD.

Comment: Then just write a space for the X coordinates, then, outside the X loop write the @ char followed by a break to exit the Y loop

Comment: Updated my answer with your requirements

Comment: Yea thanks steve I did it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To write to a specific position in a console application , use [.SetCursorPosition](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.console.setcursorposition(v=vs.110).aspx)

```
Point point = new Point(5,5);
Console.SetCursorPosition(point.X, point.Y);
Console.Write("X");
```

Alternatively you can use [.CursorLeft](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.console.cursorleft(v=vs.110).aspx) and [.CursorTop](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.console.cursortop(v=vs.110).aspx) properties which contains the current location of the cursor in the console window

```
Point point = new Point(5,5);
Console.CursorLeft = point.X;
Console.CursorTop = point.Y;
Console.Write("X");
```

---

### EDIT

Since you absolutely want to do it in a loop :

```
Point point = new Point(5,5);
for (int y = 0; y <= point.Y; y++)
{
    for (int x = 0; x <= point.X; x++)
    {
        if ((x == point.X) && (y == point.Y))
        {
            Console.Write("X");
            Break;
        }
        Console.CursorLeft++;
    }
    Console.CursorTop++;
}
```

Comment: I know pal, but I want to do it using for loops. Is it possible to do the same what this console method does you just said?

Comment: why not make a giant list of strings and store them to the list while you are looping the fors. then print it with one final killing console.write? I mean do you really need to use console write in the loop?

Comment: In my code, we only Console.Write one time, when the x and y index are the same as point.X and point.Y, then we break the loop. Otherwise we move the console cursor until we reach the point we want.